# how to make an image more blur with Imageresizing.net?

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

In the company that I am working, we are looking to replace our image resizer service and I found Imageresizing.net really useful and interesting. We use blur functionality a lot and when I look at the blur functionality in ImageResizing.net, it doesn't blur that much.

I am trying with like this: http://mywebsite.com/images/cat.jpg?blur=100
also with http://mywebsite.com/images/cat.jpg?a.blur=100

Even when you check it in their test site, it is not that much:
http://resizer.apphb.com/fountain-small.jpg?maxwidth=1020&maxheight=532&cache=no&scache=mem&a.blur=50

I am looking for blur results such as this: 
http://img.imageresizer.io/84y5ktaTIp/Lightbulb-moment.jpg?size=25%25&blur=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely large blur radius means that nearly every pixel has to be blended with every other pixel. This is extremely slow if you use a true Gaussian blur as ImageResizer currently does. We have to limit the blur radius to ensure reasonable processing time.

As blur is an infrequently used feature, we have not found parties willing to fund a high-speed C implementation of a faster 3-pass box blur approximation of guassian blur (where we could permit unlimited radius sizes and speed would not be affected).  If blur is very important to you, perhaps you would be willing to help fund this functionality?